# Android jsoup, how to select item and go to next page

Tags: android, jsoup

I want to check Hong Kong IFC mall store's iPhone4s stock state.

So, I need to go Choose products to detect the stock state "[choose product link](http://reserve.Apple.com/WebObjects/ProductReservation.woa/wo/15.0.1.0.1.3.0.7.1.10.9)". But before I go to the Choose product pages, it necessary to choose store in previous page. if I didn't choose the store, and direct go to choose product page, it will display "Your session timed out."

How do I programmatically choose IFC mall in [Apple store reserve](http://reserve.Apple.com/WebObjects/ProductReservation.woa/wa/reserveProduct?lang=en&country=HK&prelaunch=MC637ZP/A) and go to next pages by jsoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *it will display "Your session timed out."*

The session is backed by cookies. You need to maintain the session by sending the retrieved response cookies back on subsequent requests.

```
// #1.
Connection connection1 = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/firstpage");
Response response1 = connection1.execute();
Map<String, String> cookies = response1.cookies();
Document document1 = response1.parse(); // If necessary.
// ...

// #2.
Connection connection2 = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/nextpage").cookies(cookies).data("param1", "value1");
Response response2 = connection2.execute();
cookies.putAll(response2.cookies());
Document document2 = response2.parse();
// ...

// Repeat #2.
```